# How to copy arbitrary path from one UIImage to another

Tags: iphone, path, uiimage, shapes, clip

I'm new to iPhone graphics and it's a bit daunting.

The problem: I have UIImageA, and UIImageB.  Both are the same picture, except UIImageB has all the pixels values darkened.

I'd like to copy an arbitrary piece of UIImageA onto the top of UIImageB.  The end result would be a dark image, with the part of the original image bright.

My guess is that I will need to:

1. Create a "path" that is the arbitrary shape to copy.  I think I can figure this out.
2. Take UIImageA and somehow crop it or mask it to the path.
3. Copy the part of UIImageA onto UIImageB at the exact same position.

It's steps 2 and 3 that have me confused.  I've seen many examples of cropping images to a rectangle, or masking images with another pre-defined image, but nothing that exactly does this.

Does anyone have any general pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You could try Core Image.

You can do all that with CGImage in your environment. You can
use a bitmap or layer context and then later render it on whatever view
you wish.

There is a good Core Graphics Quartz tutorial at
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html